# MS MPI неправильные данные при Send struct

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mpi

Я объявил кастомную структуру для использования в send/recv.

Сама структура:

```
enum RequestType {INSERT, UPDATE};
struct Request{
    RequestType requestType;
    char node1[MAX_CHAR];
    char node2[MAX_CHAR];
    char value[MAX_CHAR];
}
```

Регистрируем ее в MPI

```
Request req;
MPI_Datatype reqTypeMPI;
MPI_Datatype reqType[4] = { MPI_INTEGER, MPI_CHAR, MPI_CHAR, MPI_CHAR };
int blocklen[4] = { 1, MAX_CHAR, MAX_CHAR, MAX_CHAR };
MPI_Aint disp[4];
MPI_Get_address(&req.requestType, &disp[0]);
MPI_Get_address(&req.node1, &disp[1]);
MPI_Get_address(&req.node2, &disp[2]);
MPI_Get_address(&req.value, &disp[3]);
disp[3] = disp[3] - disp[2];
disp[2] = disp[2] - disp[1];
disp[1] = disp[1] - disp[0];
disp[0] = 0;
MPI_Type_create_struct(4, blocklen, disp, reqType, &reqTypeMPI);
MPI_Type_commit(&reqTypeMPI);
```

Далее делаем просто send/recv

```
// send
Request request;
strcpy_s(request.node1, node1.c_str());
strcpy_s(request.node2, node2.c_str());
strcpy_s(request.value, value.c_str());
request.requestType = INSERT;
MPI_Send(&request, 1, requestDatatype, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

// recv
Request request;
MPI_Status status;
MPI_Recv(&request, 1, requestDatatype, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, 
&status);
```

Все данные передаются корректно, кроме поля value. Например, пусть node1 = "node", node2 = "node2", value = "value", requestType = INSERT. Тогда в результате я получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: нужно больше самодостаточности в примере (желательно до уровня скорировал-собрал)...